# Titanium Configuration error

Tags: titanium-mobile

I spent much time to fix titanium mobile web app run process, I just trying to execute an sample mobile web app created, while running the app I'm getting below screen.It doesn't show an exact result.At very first time it worked perfectly.But can't able configure android sdk with it.So gone through instillation after many uninstalls[image]. getting below error screen while running.

Answer (score 0):

The go to solutions for Titanium Mobile seems to be to do a project clean and see if you get the error again.  There have been a time or two where I get some odd error after changing something that seems minor and an odd error is returned.  Clean the project seems to help in some cases.

From in the IDE go to Project=>Clean...

Comment: @Martin.. thanks for you answer.I fixed it by adding proper System Path at Environment variables.